# I'm having problems scraping and extracting a value

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

So I am trying to web scrape Indeed.com 
I have this set of code

```
base_url <- "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q="
test_url <- read_html("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=IBM&l=Anywhere&filter=0&start=0")
total_jobs <-test_url %>%
  html_node('#searchCountPages') %>%
  html_text()
```

I am trying to get the total number of jobs out as an Integer but there are multiple problems. In that code above, total_jobs is a character vector (I think) and its something like "Page 1 of 1,128 jobs"

I am basically trying to extract the value of 1128 in this example as an integer but I can't can someone please help me?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right nodes? Maybe just use RegEx to get your value?

Comment: I don't know, I am doing this for the first time so I could be terribly wrong. Edit- what's regex?

Comment: regex isnt working either

Comment: There is probably a better way but try adding these two lines: `stringr::str_extract_all("\\d+") %>% 
  purrr::map(max)`. Note that this may not give you the 1128 since it only gives me 600 something. Better to use an API imho

Answer (score 0):

Following @NelsonGon tip:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

test_url <- read_html("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=IBM&l=Anywhere&filter=0&start=0")
total_jobs <- test_url %>%
  html_node('#searchCountPages') %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  str_extract_all(., "\\d+") %>%
  gsub(",", "", .) %>% 
  unlist(.) %>% 
  as.integer() %>% 
  max()
```

Comment: With this I am still not getting 1128, the answer I am getting after running this chunk is 186

Comment: I don't get that number after scraping URL you posted, but tr changed code.